# Trying to install react-native-scaling-drawer for version 0.60 but it gives error

Tags: react-native

I want to use react-native-scaling-drawer in my react-native application.

also i  follow each and every given step for installation from github

https://github.com/melihberberolu/react-native-scaling-drawer.

but every time it give error.

[image]

how can solve this problem please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have already downloaded `react-navigation`. The `react-native-scaling-drawer` module you are trying to install is already in `react-navigation` That's why there's a collision.

Usage

```js
import ScalingDrawer from 'react-native-scaling-drawer';
```

Comment: Actually I'm unable to install the module 'react-native-scaling-drawer' from the npm.

Comment: I don't think you understand my answer. I mean, you don't have to install `react-native-scaling-drawer` because you've already installed `react-navigation`. Already the module is in `react-navigation`.

Comment: @AbhishekAhirwar If my answer has helped you solve your problem, please choose my answer.